# Grammar for parsing multiple calls?

Tags: parsing, grammar, recursive-descent

As a side project and learning experiment, I'm writing my own programming language with no extra premade tools, such as LLVM.

I've already written my own recursive descent parser, but I'm having a problem trying to think of the logistics of parsing a statement like this:

```
x()()[0]()
```

I can't think of a good way to make a parse tree/AST out of this. I've tried reading the grammars of other programming languages (notably Python and C#), but I just can't figure out how they do it.

How would I write something to parse the above grammar?

Answer (score 0):

From an AST perspective, it probably helps to imagine that you have some sort of "function call" node, with one child representing the expression representing the function to call and one child per expression denoting an argument. For example, the code `fn()()[0]()` might look like this:

```
                   +--------+
                   |  call  |
                   +--------+
              function /  \ args
                      /  (null)
                     /
                +-----------+
                | selection |
                +-----------+
               array /  \ index
                    /    0
                   /
              +--------+
              |  call  |
              +--------+
         function / \ args
                 /   (null)     
                /
           +--------+
           |  call  |
           +--------+
     function / \ args
            fn   0
```

In terms of how to parse something like this, I'd recommend treating the function call as a postfix operator like array selection (`arr[index]`) or member selection (`object.field`). A CFG fragment for this might look like this:

```
 Expr --> Expr(ArgList) |  
          /* other expression types */
```

From a recursive descent perspective, after you've parsed an expression, you'd do a lookahead to see if there's an open parenthesis token after it. If so, that means that whatever you just read should be treated as the function component of a function call expression, and what you're about to read is the argument list.

Comment: I find it easier to think about both call and index as postfix operators (which happen to enclose another operand or list). Postfix operators have maximum precedence, so you can immediately attach the left operand; normal parenthesis parsing will handle the subscript/arguments (more or less normal). Of course, bison is easier :).

Comment: @rici That's a really good point. (It's been a while since I taught a compilers class.) Let me go fix that.

Comment: Hello, I'm very close to understanding this. What is stopping that CFG fragment from looking for itself, not finding it, and erroring?

Comment: @boyned You'd have to be careful about how you implemented the parser. You could alternatively have the grammar be something like CallExpr -> Expr OptCall, with OptCall -> e | (ArgList).

Comment: is `e` different from `Expr`?

Comment: @boyned I was using e as shorthand for epsilon, as in "nothing."

Comment: Oh, I see. That was what I had before, only that seems to be like my problem of it only getting the one call.